# How can I include current provided date information also in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, case

I am fething top loosers data for 1 day based on this query

```
SELECT symbol_name,close_val,current_day,SUM(close_val-prevclose_val) AS toploosers   
FROM  historical_data
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND '2015-12-18' 
GROUP BY symbol_name
ORDER BY toploosers ASC;

CREATE TABLE `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL
);



INSERT INTO `historical_data` (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`, `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`) VALUES
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-11', 1611.00, 1620.00, 1570.30, 1581.25, 1579.00, 1602.10),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-11', 709.00, 713.70, 672.25, 680.60, 683.45, 707.10),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-14', 1572.50, 1584.70, 1545.00, 1559.55, 1557.60, 1581.25),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-14', 679.10, 689.00, 668.00, 683.25, 683.65, 680.60),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-15', 1564.70, 1580.50, 1558.00, 1572.10, 1567.50, 1559.55),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-15', 688.00, 694.20, 675.75, 691.35, 688.25, 683.25),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-16', 1581.50, 1617.90, 1578.00, 1587.15, 1589.00, 1572.10),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-16', 697.00, 710.60, 694.25, 698.55, 699.15, 691.35),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-17', 1596.10, 1642.00, 1576.05, 1628.20, 1636.80, 1587.15),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-17', 708.00, 723.75, 705.70, 721.10, 720.00, 698.55),
    ('WOCKPHARMA', '2015-12-18', 1630.00, 1654.85, 1620.30, 1627.55, 1631.00, 1628.20),
    ('YESBANK', '2015-12-18', 717.90, 727.45, 713.60, 718.70, 720.20, 721.10);
```

The Result I am getting is

```
symbol_name      close_val  current_day                        toploosers

YESBANK     721.1   December, 17 2015 00:00:00  20.15
WOCKPHARMA  1628.2  December, 17 2015 00:00:00  40.4
```

How can I fetch the current date (2015-12-18) close_val also ??

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3693b/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT symbol_name,
       Sum(Case when current_day = '2015-12-18' then close_val else 0 end) as close_val,
       Max(Case when current_day = '2015-12-18' then current_day else null end) as current_day,
       Sum(Case when current_day =  DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 1 DAY) then close_val else 0 end) as close_val,
       SUM(close_val-prevclose_val) AS toploosers 
FROM historical_data 
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND '2015-12-18' 
GROUP BY symbol_name 
ORDER BY toploosers ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you , but i want to fetch the current day close value aslo as well as prevoius days close value also in the query ,

Comment: The query you provided is just fetching me current date's close value only , i want to include both the close prices (curent date's as well as interval date's).

Comment: Working perfect , i can't ask for more , thanks a lot again .... now i can continutue with my java and javascript work .. :)

Comment: is it possible to keep the name of close_val different ??

Comment: Yes you can give alias name as you want